# Strip/Remove debug symbols and archive names from a static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, debug-symbols, otool

I have a static library (C++) (say, `libmylib_DARWIN.a` and `libmylib_LINUX.a` for 2 architectures) compiled on my Mac using clang (`Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)` if is of any relevance).

Right now, there are two problems:

1. The static library (using a current build configuration) contains debug symbols
2. It also shows names of the object files that were used for the archive

   `otool -Iv libmylib_DARWIN.a`

   `Archive : libmylib_DARWIN.a
   libmylib_DARWIN.a(firstobjectfile.cpp.o)
   libmylib_DARWIN.a(secondobjectfile.cpp.o)
   ....`

I would like to remove **both** the debug symbols and archived filenames from this library. I wonder if there is a convenient way to do it **without** changing my build configuration.

- will `strip` on Mac do it for both DARWIN- and LINUX-built libraries? Anything I should pay attention too?
- `strip` doesn't seem to remove the archive filenames

There are some similar questions on SO; however, the ones I found deal with either iOS, Objective C, do not talk about multiplatform, and do not mention archive names.

Comment: Just currious; "I would like to remove both ..." -  *why*?

Comment: both the debug symbols and filenames disclose information that I legally should not share. With filenames, it can technically be solved by renaming (which is very inconvenient), and I would like to strip debug symbols for multiple architectures from my home OS - also a convenience.

Comment: extract the original .o files with `ar`, run `strip` on them individually, rename them, repack them again with `ar` or `ld`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script implements Sigismondo's suggestion (unpacks the archive, strips each object file individually, renames them `1000.o`, `1001.o`, etc., and repacks). The parameters for `ar crus` may vary depending on your version of `ar`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: repack.sh file.a

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "usage: repack file.a"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -d tmprepack ]; then
    /bin/rm -rf tmprepack
fi

mkdir tmprepack
cp $1 tmprepack
pushd tmprepack

basename=${1##*/}

ar xv $basename
/bin/rm -f $basename
i=1000
for p in *.o ; do
    strip -d $p
    mv $p ${i}.o
    ((i++))
done

ar crus $basename *.o
mv $basename ..

popd
/bin/rm -rf tmprepack
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. This script definitely removes the debug symbols and changes filenames, but now I cannot link to it as before. Undefined symbols - as references are undefined now....

Comment: Sorry about that, try changing the strip line to `strip -d $p` to strip only debug symbols.

Comment: That script worked on Mac for a Mac version of the library. However, it refused to work on the LINUX one. However, it also worked on LINUX for LINUX library. That solves 90% of the problem. I'll accept it if nothing better comes up. Thanks!

Comment: Thx for the script!
Only addition I had to do on macOS was to only strip .o files (`if [[ $p == *.o ]]; then`), and use the 
"-S" flag (-d means something else): `strip -S $p`